# How to use Netflix on ArchLinux and Kodi 17.6?

Tags: kodi, archlinux

I want to watch Netflix with my raspberry pi.

Currently I installed [Arch linux](https://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv8/broadcom/raspberry-pi-3) and installed [kodi-rbp](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kodi#Raspberry_Pi_.28all_generations.29). Kodi 17.6 works fine with the command `kodi-standalone` however I could not find Netflix add on. Tried to install the Kodi 18 via the Aur but I get

```
==> ERROR: kodi-git is not available for the 'armv7h' architecture.

==> ERROR: An unknown error has occurred. Exiting...
```

How can I watch netflix with my current setup?

Answer (score 2):

Kodi 18 (`kodi-git`) from AUR is only available for the 686 and x86 plattform not the Pi's ARM.

[Rumor](https://www.phoronix.com/forums/forum/phoronix/general-discussion/939773-kodi-is-getting-a-proper-netflix-plugin?p=939927#post939927) has it that you need to build it yourself:

> The Netflix plugin works fine on Raspberry Pi3 with an early version of LibreELEC 9.0, however for Netflix to work it requires an (as yet) unreleased version of Kodi 18 (or build it yourself, from the "agile" branch).

With another user:

> My understanding is that DRM is fundamentally incompatible with free software – there has to be a blob somewhere. Thus, portability is at the mercy of those who make that blob – good luck getting it working on a commercially insignificant platform.

Which I am afraid will hold true for the Pi :(

Comment: Thanks for the post. Yeah I am new to building Kodi18 myself so I guess I need to wait a little